# Invalid view state exception in asp.net. do you know any solution?

Tags: asp.net

this problem make me crazy!
i have asp.net website it raise periodically this error (in IE8):

```
    System.Web.HttpException: Invalid viewstate.
       at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
       at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler
.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    ,...
```

or (in IE6)

```
System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
```

or (in IE7)

```
System.FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
```

i set enableViewStateMac in web.config to false and defined machinekey in my web.config and defined UTF-8 encoding for every page 
but i received this errors.

do you have any solution?

best regards

Comment: @mmtemporary this could happens for many reasons, maybe you do not have set correctly the setup on web.config, maybe you compress the pages and set error length, maybe you change the content of the page after the view state is set, maybe you break the content... many reasons... its difficult to some one help you with only this informations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing databinding on the page more than once when a page loads?  This error will occur if you do that.

Comment: In response to the w4ymo's comment about binding -  he is of course, correct about checking IsPostBack.  However, I was referring to more than one control on your page data binding.  Binding the same control twice won't cause this mesage.  Just bad data in some cases.

Comment: i bind multi control in page load (no in postback). please give me example which binding is incorrect?

Comment: If you are binding when the page first loads you should bind using (!Page.IsPostBack) but if you are dynamically adding ascx controls programmatically you will need to bind these on every subsequent post back.

Comment: @mmtemporary: here is some pseudocode: Page_Load() { addControls(); if (!Page.IsPostBack) { bind(); } }

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding during your `Page_Load` event use the `IsPostBack` flag of the your `Page` object so binding only occurs once during load.

e.g.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //Perform Binding Here
}
```

But if you are dynamically adding ascx controls programmatically you will need to bind these on every subsequent post back.